# How to know how many strings does a string array contain?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I've a string array:

```
char array[128][128];
```

To add strings in this array, I read a file, and append a line if `"192.168.101.2"` is contained in that line:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if (strstr(line, "192.168.101.2") != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        strcpy(array[i], line);
        i++;
    }
    
}
```

Now, I would like to know how many strings this array contains. I've tried:
`sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, but it always returns 128. How can I achieve this?
And, how can i pass an array of strings to a function? I've tried:

```
void array_length(char array[int][int]);
```

but:

```
main.c:15:31: error: expected expression before ‘int’
   15 | void array_length(char array [int][int]);
```

Comment: When the loop ends, the value of `i` will have the number of strings in the array. Save it and use it.

Comment: And please, one question per question. But quite honestly, how to pass arrays of arrays should be taught by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: I know, but how can I calculate the number of strings without the i index?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without `i`? You must have that index to store into the correct element of your array. If you really want to do it without a counter you can add a sentinel, i.e. an array element that is defined to be invalid. For strings that could be an empty string after the last string read from your file.

Answer (score 4):

> How to know how many strings does a string array contain?

C does not really have arrays, as they are in most other languages. Sure, you have array types, and can initialize arrays directly. But at *runtime*, array is just a pointer. There is no additional runtime information about it.

So, you have to keep track of both array maximum size and how many (or which) elements of array are used/initialized *yourself*.

So, here's code:

```
// char *array[128] might be better, but would require use of malloc for every string 
char array[128][128];

// array size in bytes / one row size in bytes = number of rows
const size_t array_capacity = sizeof (array) / sizeof(array[0]); 

// update len as you add strings of text 
size_t array_len = 0;
```